# Multiplication of two 16-bit numbers without using mul or imul instructions

Tags: assembly, x86-16, multiplication, emu8086

I am to multiply two 16-bit numbers without using `MUL` in the emu8086 microprocessor.
Below is how I had done it:

```
MOV AX, 000H
MOV DX, AX
MOV AL, [4000H]
MOV CL, [4002H]
ADD AL, CL
MOV [4003H], AL
DAA
MOV AL, [4004H]
MOV CL, [4005H]
ADC AL, CL
MOV [4006H], AL
DAA
MOV AL,[000H]
ADC AL, AL
MOV [4007H],AL
HLT
```

[image]

But I think the answer is not correct.

Comment: That code looks like 2-digit BCD addition that can produce a 3rd digit of output. e.g. like 35 + 82 = 117. Not multiplication at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fluent in Assembly but an algorithm using only bitwise operations and addition could look something like this

```c
multiply (unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
  if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
  int c = 0;
  while (a != 0) {
    if (a & 1) {
      c += b;
    }
    a = a >> 1;
    b = b << 1;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
MOV AX, 0000H
MOV BX, [2000H]
MOV CX, [2002H]
MOV DX, 0000H
MOV SI, 000FH

LOOP:
SHR CX, 1
JC ADDITION

ADDITION:
ADD AX, BX

SHR BX, 1

DEC SI
JNZ LOOP

MOV [2004H], AX
HLT
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYu2P.png)

Comment: This code is awfully wrong! I sincerely hope that you improve it. Please consider these: If this multiplication is non-widening, why then do you zero DX beforehand? And why do you have only 15 iterations instead of 16 for a word-sized number?

Comment: BX should be shifting left, larger partial products for higher bits of the original CX input, like in the C answer.  Also, you can use CX!=0 as the loop condition, no need for a separate counter.